# WPF Window closes automatically soon after loaded

Tags: c#, wpf

WPF MainWindow closes automatically soon after showed for 1 sec. I have only this mainwindow in the wpf project. There is no error showing when running the application. Without showing any error, the MainWindow simply closes soon after loaded. There is nothing code in App.xaml.cs.

Here is the code written in the MainWindow.

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
      private Socket clientSocket;
      private byte[] buffer;

      public MainWindow()
      {
        InitializeComponent();
      }

      private bool CheckField()
      {
        if (txtIP.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please specify IP Address");
            return false;
        }

        if (txtPort.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please specify Port Number");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

     private void btnGreen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
        if(CheckField()) SendMessage("GREEN");
     }

     private void btnRed_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
        if (CheckField()) SendMessage("RED");
     }

     private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {          
        try
        {
            clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // if below code commented, window will not close

            clientSocket.BeginConnect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 
            3333), new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
     }

     private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
     {
        clientSocket.EndConnect(ar);
     }    

     public void SendMessage(string xmlstring)
     {
        try
        {
            byte[] xmlbuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlstring);
            clientSocket.BeginSend(xmlbuffer, 0, xmlbuffer.Length, 
            SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
      }

      private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
      {
        clientSocket.EndSend(ar);
        buffer = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
      }

   }
```

What's wrong in here ???

Comment: anything in app.xaml.cs

Comment: @Steve There is nothing code in App.xaml.cs. Only  StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">

Comment: Loads fine for me. Try removing all xaml between your <grid> tags. If that doesn't work, please post all xaml too.

Comment: Have you tried putting a try catch in ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)? It looks like something in your socket connection is throwing an exception which isn't handled.

Comment: Any clues in the output window?